# Is it possible to save an instance of a class in a file in C++ easily?

Tags: c++, file, class, save, instance

Let's say I have a class (containing instances of another class)

This is environment.h

```
class environment
{

    public:
    int historycounter = 0;
    vector<single_event> history; //containing a vector of type single_event (another class)
    bool insertion_started = false;

   private:

};
```

Now let's assume that I create an instance of that class in my main file Main.cpp
In Main:

```
#include "environment.h"
environment env1; //create an instance of the class environment
env1.history_counter = 5; //inelegant example to show that I'm inserting values to env1
```

My question: Is there a magic simple way to save env1 into a file?
In my naive mind I'm hoping to see something like:

```
SaveToFile(env1, "filename.whatever");
environment test;
LoadfromFile(test, "filename.whatever");

cout<<test.history_counter; //the goal is to have the number 5 printed
```

I hope there is such a way

Comment: There is no "built-in" method in C++ that I am aware of. You need to use a serialization library or write your own serialization routines.

Comment: thanks for the reply Matt, What is the simplest way to achieve the goal in my case? what way would you suggest me?

Comment: In the past I've used boost::serialization: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html Or just rolled my own serializers. I don't really think either approach is as simple as with other languages though.

Comment: Serialization is seriously difficult to get right. I recommend using Boost. At least until you get familiar with the ideas and issues.

Comment: Writing binary data to a file is pretty simple if you are using POD. If your class has pointers to things allocated on the heap, you need to specify what exactly those pointers mean.